# How to compare if two ImageButtons use the exact same drawable resource in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, button

I want to create a method that checks if two ImageButtons use the exact same drawable resource as a background image in Android Studio.

I tried something similar to this:

```
public void isBackgroundImageTheSame() {
        if(findViewById(R.id.btn1).getDrawableState() == findViewById(R.id.btn2).getDrawableState()){
            //Execute some code
        }
```

However this didnt work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to?  Your state should be driving your UI, not the other way around.  You should be able to tell if they are by comparing their models in your UI state, without actually querying a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawableState isn't what you are looking for, I think you can use a method called getBackground.getConstantState  on the ImageButtons you have, and then compare them if they are the same:

Here is a code maybe will help you:

```kotlin
public boolean areBackgroundImagesTheSame(ImageButton button1, ImageButton button2) {
    Drawable drawable1 = button1.getBackground();
    Drawable drawable2 = button2.getBackground();

    if (drawable1 == null && drawable2 == null) {
        // both ImageButtons have no background image
        return true;
    } else if (drawable1 == null || drawable2 == null) {
        // only one ImageButton has a background image
        return false;
    } else {
        // both ImageButtons have a background image, compare them
        return drawable1.getConstantState().equals(drawable2.getConstantState());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can be simplified with Objects.equals